# Pull down menu cut in half when in form

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Currently, I am using xcode with swiftui.
In the code below, it shows the disclosure group inside the form. However, when I run this code, the pull-down menu is cut in half. Would anyone know why this is happening. This image is show below.
[Picture of pulldown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NB3z.png)

```
Form{
DisclosureGroup("\(diet)", isExpanded: $isExpandedDiet){
                        VStack {
                            ForEach(listOfDiet, id:\.self) { list in
                                Text("\(list)")
                                    .font(.title3)
                                    .padding(.all)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        self.diet = list
                                        withAnimation {
                                            self.isExpandedDiet.toggle()
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }.accentColor(.white)
                    .font(.title3)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.all)
                    .background(Color(red: 0.1803921568627451, green: 0.8196078431372549, blue: 0.8784313725490196))
                    .cornerRadius(8)
}
```

Comment: What is it supposed to look like? It seems ok to me

Comment: @aheze it only covers half of the full length.

Answer (score 0):

instead of a VStack you could try a ScrollView, and add a frame,

.frame(width: xxx, height: yyy)